# Reading screen's resolution with QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp

In the initialization of my script I would have to read the resolution of the screen so I know how to resize the browser's window size.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that can get the resolution for either the primary monitor or all multiple monitors.
Additionally, the last function returns a boolean for whether you have multiple monitors or not.

```
'*******************************************************************
'TotalScreenWidth & TotalScreenHeight
'by Michael Innes
'October 2012

'Intended for getting the total resolution when you have multiple monitors
'Returns the width and the height (respectively) across all the screens.
Function TotalScreenWidth()
    TotalScreenWidth = Window("regexpwndtitle:=Program Manager").GetROProperty("width")
End Function

Function TotalScreenHeight()
    TotalScreenHeight = Window("regexpwndtitle:=Program Manager").GetROProperty("height")
End Function


'*******************************************************************
'ScreenWidth & ScreenHeight
'by Michael Innes
'October 2012

'Retrieves the width and height (respectively) of the primary screen (the screen that the taskbar is on)
'This only works if the taskbar is at the bottom of the screen
Function ScreenWidth()
    ScreenWidth = Window("object class:=Shell_TrayWnd").GetROProperty("width")
End Function

Function ScreenHeight()
    ScreenHeight = Window("object class:=Shell_TrayWnd").GetROProperty("height") + Window("object class:=Shell_TrayWnd").GetROProperty("y")
End Function


'*******************************************************************
'MultipleMonitors
'by Michael Innes
'October 2012

'Returns a boolean that determines if the computer has multiple monitors attached.

'This only works if the taskbar is at the bottom of the left-most screen.
'If the taskbar is on the right-most monitor, this function will incorrectly report the multiple monitors as being False.
Function MultipleMonitors()
    MultipleMonitors = Eval((screenWidth <> TotalScreenWidth) OR (screenHeight <> TotalScreenHeight))
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will try it on see what it looks like ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite straight forward, find the desktop window and get its dimensions.

```
width = Window("text:=Program Manager").GetROProperty("width")
height = Window("text:=Program Manager").GetROProperty("height")
Print width & ", " & height
```

This works for single monitors, I haven't checked what happens when you have multiple monitors.

Comment: ok thanks Motti. That would have been my next question jeje;)

Comment: If anyone can help please go ahead!